# How to extract certain portion of String using RegEx expression?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I would like to extract certain values from the given String

String --> 1**ABCDE**23

I need only ABCDE from the above string value. Always skip the first value(1) and get next 5 characters(ABCDE) and skip the rest(23)

Appreciate your help

Comment: This is not a regex writing service. What have you tried so far to do this yourself?

Comment: Always skip the first value = `^.`, get the next 5 characters = `(.{5})`, skip the rest = ` `

Comment: Thank you! sln and Ken for your reply. When I tried checking online tool (https://regex101.com/) with RegEx : \d+(.{5}) it is showing correct output but apparently its not working.

Comment: It is working. You do not know how to use it, and no one can help you because you did not provide us neither the code you have, nor what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

> Always skip the first value(1) and get next 5 characters(ABCDE) and skip the rest(23)

This is just extracting a substring from a string! You don't need a regex for this - there has to be a faster function for that in the language you're using, assuming you're using a sane language.

Here are some examples:

- Java: `String abcde = "1ABCDE23".substring(1, 6);`
- JavaScript: `var abcde = "1ABCDE23".substring(1, 6);`
- C++: `std::string abcde = std::string("1ABCDE23").substr(1, 5);`
- Python: `abcde = "1ABCDE23"[1:6]`
- PHP: `$abcde = substr("1ABCDE23", 1, 5);`
- C#: `string abcde = "1ABCDE23".Substring(1, 5);`
- Perl: `$abcde = substr "1ABCDE23", 1, 5;`
- Ruby: `abcde = "1ABCDE23"[1...6]`

If you're using an insane language that has a regex engine with support for capturing groups but not a facility for extracting substrings from strings, you can run this regex (which is [suggested by sln](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/73295559)) and take the first capturing group:

```
^.(.{5}).*

^          the match must be at the beginning of the string
 .         match any character
  (    )   put what's matched by the parenthesized expression into the 1st capturing group
   .{5}    match 5 characters; any character goes
        .* match 0 or more characters; any character goes
```